# byte indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python-3.x

```
itens = []
lugares = []
lugar = None

from pickle import dumps

 # Definição das funções:

def adlugar(nome, lookmsg, passagens, objs = None):
    global lugares
    global dic
    dic = dumps(nome)
    dic = {"nome": nome, "look": lookmsg, "passagens": passagens.split(" # ")}
    if objs:
        itens = objs.split(" # ")
        dic["invent"] = itens
    lugares.append(nome.lower())
def aditen(nome, lookmsg, getmsg, pegavel = "não"):
    global itens
    global dic
    dic = dumps(nome)
    dic = {"nome": nome, "look": lookmsg, "get": getmsg, "pg": pegavel}
    itens.append(nome.lower())
def look(obj):
    global itens
    global lugar
    if obj in itens:
        obj = obj.lower()
        obj = dumps(obj)
        if obj in lugar["invent"]:
            return(obj[look])
lugar = dumps("casa")
adlugar("casa", "casa.", "quintal", "livro")
aditen("livro", "livro", "livro", "sim")
look("livro")
```

Eu estou com problemas na manipulação de dicionários. Eu defini uma função que cria dicionários, e outra que invoca os valores a partir de índices. Porém dentro da função que chama os valores eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> ```
> if obj in lugar["invent"]:
>     TipeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str
> ```

Em primeiro, quando eu uso a função adlugar() ela deveria criar um dicionário, no caso assim: casa = {"nome": "casa", "look": "casa", "passagens": "quintal", "invent": "livro"}
 A função aditen deveria criar um dicionário livro = {"nome": "livro", "look": "livro", "get": "livro", "pg": "sim"}.
 Note que as duas funções usam o atributo nome para criar uma variável dumps(nome) para o dicionário (o motivo é que não se pode criar variáveis string, e aminha solução foi usar o dumps para transformá-las em sequências de bytes).
 Já a função look usa a variável lugar para saber em qual dicionário ela deve verificar o índice "invent". Se o objeto estiver neste índice, ele retorna o que estiver no índice "look" do obj.
 Porém, quando eu invoco o comando, ele diz que o meu índice não pode ser uma string, e sim um "integer" ou um "slice", o que são índices de listas. isso quer dizer que ele está tratando os diconários como se fossem listas?

Comment: Seu código, no geral, não faz muito sentido. Tem como você descrever seu problema e comentar o que cada parte do seu código deveria fazer? Notas: 1) Utilizar a função `dump` antes de criar o objeto não faz sentido; 2) Fazer `return(print(obj[look]))` também não faz sentido; 3) `lugar` é uma *string*, acessar o índice `invent` da mesma não faz sentido (**essa é a causa do atual erro**); 4) O que deveria ser este `invent` que não é utilizado em nenhuma outra parte do código?

Comment: Pedro, logo abaixo da sua pergunta, existe o link [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/199385/edit), use-o e adicione o conteúdo desses dois comentários à pergunta, pois são essenciais para alguém buscar entender seu problema. Se possível, diga também porque está utilizando a biblioteca `pickle`.

Comment: O slice retorna uma parte da lista em questão. Por exemplo, fazer a lista `foo = [0, 1, 2, 3]` e colocar `print(foo[0:2])`, retornará `[0, 1]`, pois retorna a parte da lista `foo` iniciando na posição 0, com 2 elementos. A expressão `0:2`, no caso, é o que é chamado de slice.